# With two different js both generating an openlayers map each does not replace the other in the same div

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Having a simple div with id='map'

and an JS:

```
var MapPlayOL = {
    myinfo: "MapObjectOL",

    simpleMap : function() {
        var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.82, 50.41]),
          zoom: 7
        })
        });
    },

    mainMap : function() {
        var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
            });
    },

    clearMap : function() {
        $( "#map" ).html("");
    }
```

Executing MapPlayOL.simpleMap() fills the map. Afterwards executing MapPlayOL.mainMap() does not replace the content of the div: no new map appears.
Same happens vice versa. Only executing MapPlayOL.clearMap() inbetween allows the second call to  replace the content of the div.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does add the map, but it does not superimpose them.  If you set the map div height to 100% you will see the second map, you need to scroll down to see it below the first.

To superimpose maps you would need 2 divs inside a container

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="map1" class="map"></div>
  <div id="map2" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

and position them in the css

```
  .map {
    position: absolute;
  }
```